# How to calculate this summation numerically?

Tags: summation, compile, function-compile

I want to calculate this summation numerically:

$\sum_{n=1}^{10^{10}}\frac{1}{n^3\sin(n)^2}$

First I try

```
NSum[1/(n^3 Sin[n]^2), {n, 1, 10^10}]
```

however it gives a wrong answer with warning `"NIntegrate failed to converge to prescribed accuracy after 9 recursive bisections in n near {n} = {201.188}. NIntegrate obtained 0.2048775323986418 and 0.19848142574386735 for the integral and  error estimates"` and `"Euler-Maclaurin sum failed to converge to requested error tolerance"`.

Then I try

```
f = Compile[{{k, _Integer}}, Sum[1/(n^3 Sin[n]^2), {n, 1, k}], CompilationTarget -> "C"];
f[10^10]
```

and it gives me a warning `"Numerical error encountered; proceeding with uncompiled evaluation"` and no result is provided.

Lastly I try `FunctionCompile`, like

```
g = FunctionCompile[Function[Typed[k, "MachineInteger"], Sum[1/(n^3 Sin[n]^2), {n, 1, k}]]]
```

and this gives an error `"TypeError. For the function Sin no matching candidate that takes an argument with the type Integer64 was found"`. So I want to know to calculate this summation in mathematica appropriately with speed.

Comment: If the goal is to do the brute force approach then the following should work `k = 6;
NSum[1/(n^3 Sin[n]^2), {n, 1, 10^k}, NSumTerms -> 10^k] // Timing`. Check calculations for `k=6, 7, 8`. This will help you to make a decision on how to proceed further.

Comment: `Sum[N[1/(n^3 Sin[n]^2)], {n, 1, 10^4}, Method -> "Procedural"]` gives 30.3145 from 10^4 and onwards though becomes impractical to calculate beyond 10^8 but this is kind of irrelevant since the error is around 10^-24 at that point.

Comment: I would like to add that this is a very-very difficult sum deeply related to the number theory. In fact, it is not even know if it converges in infinite limits, see here https://mathoverflow.net/q/24579/41145 This means, that even if you manage to compute the finite sum, no conclusion can be drawn about the infinite one!